# Heroku deployment taking long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment, react-on-rails

Recently we introduced React in our Rails application. After adding react deployment is taking long time it takes around half an hour to complete due to asset pre-compilation.

Any suggestion to make deployment faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your assets locally and push to heroku.

Follow below steps:

1. Run command: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`
2. Push all compiled files with menifest file to heroku.